# ccache and precompiled header

Tags: gcc, header, precompiled, ccache

I'm using precompiled header and CCACHE to speed up my compilation (GCC 5.3.1)

The two works separatly (I have a speed up x2 for precompiled, and x25 for CCACHE on second run), but I have trouble to make them work together (I have only cache miss when looking at CCACHE stats).

Do you see any reason why ccache could not manage to work with precompiled header ?

Here are the CCACHE stats

```
cache directory                     /work1/heyho/cache/ccache
primary config                      /work1/heyho/cache/ccache/ccache.conf
secondary config      (readonly)    /etc/ccache.conf
cache hit (direct)                     1
cache hit (preprocessed)               0
cache miss                          1016
called for link                       12
compile failed                         1
files in cache                      1490
cache size                         627.1 MB
max cache size                       5.0 GB
```

Here is an example of CCACHE log (on second run)

```
[x] === CCACHE 3.2.1 STARTED =========================================
[x] Config: (default) base_dir =
[x] Config: (environment) cache_dir = /work1/gwen/cache/ccache
[x] Config: (default) cache_dir_levels = 2
[x] Config: (default) compiler =
[x] Config: (default) compiler_check = mtime
[x] Config: (default) compression = false
[x] Config: (default) compression_level = 6
[x] Config: (default) cpp_extension =
[x] Config: (default) direct_mode = true
[x] Config: (default) disable = false
[x] Config: (default) extra_files_to_hash =
[x] Config: (default) hard_link = false
[x] Config: (environment) hash_dir = true
[x] Config: (environment) log_file = /tmp/cache.debug
[x] Config: (default) max_files = 0
[x] Config: (/work1/gwen/cache/ccache/ccache.conf) max_size = 5.0G
[x] Config: (default) path =
[x] Config: (environment) prefix_command =
[x] Config: (default) read_only = false
[x] Config: (default) read_only_direct = false
[x] Config: (default) recache = false
[x] Config: (default) run_second_cpp = false
[x] Config: (/work1/gwen/cache/ccache/ccache.conf) sloppiness = time_macros
[x] Config: (default) stats = true
[x] Config: (default) temporary_dir =
[x] Config: (default) umask =
[x] Config: (default) unify = false
[x] Command line: ccache /usr/bin/c++ -DUSE_PRECOMPILED -Dbluevision_EXPORTS -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -I/work-crypt/gwen/workspace/bluecime/bluevision/src -I/work-crypt/gwen/workspace/bluecime/bluevision/build/None_Linux-4.4.14-200.fc22.x86_64/src -std=c++11 -fPIC -Werror -Wall -march=corei7-avx -mavx -msse4.1 -msse4.2 -fabi-version=6 -mavx2 -Winvalid-pch -include precompiled_header.hpp -o CMakeFiles/bluevision.dir/descriptor/histogram/integral_image.cpp.o -c /work-crypt/gwen/workspace/bluecime/bluevision/src/descriptor/histogram/integral_image.cpp
[x] Hostname: kernavo.com
[x] Working directory: /work-crypt/gwen/workspace/bluecime/bluevision/build/None_Linux-4.4.14-200.fc22.x86_64/src
[x] Detected use of precompiled header: precompiled_header.hpp.gch
[x] Source file: /work-crypt/gwen/workspace/bluecime/bluevision/src/descriptor/histogram/integral_image.cpp
[x] Object file: CMakeFiles/bluevision.dir/descriptor/histogram/integral_image.cpp.o
[x] Trying direct lookup
[x] Looking for object file hash in /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/3/9/67544dd3c9bebe61712bf8bcc68c23-10829.manifest
[x] Did not find object file hash in manifest
[x] Running preprocessor
[x] Executing /usr/bin/c++ -fPIC -std=c++11 -fPIC -Werror -Wall -march=corei7-avx -mavx -msse4.1 -msse4.2 -fabi-version=6 -mavx2 -Winvalid-pch -DUSE_PRECOMPILED -Dbluevision_EXPORTS -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -I/work-crypt/gwen/workspace/bluecime/bluevision/src -I/work-crypt/gwen/workspace/bluecime/bluevision/build/None_Linux-4.4.14-200.fc22.x86_64/src -include precompiled_header.hpp -fpch-preprocess -E /work-crypt/gwen/workspace/bluecime/bluevision/src/descriptor/histogram/integral_image.cpp
[x] Got object file hash from preprocessor
[x] Object file /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/c/b/960271b46a4eb133ebec4407f8b799-193981.o not in cache
[x] Running real compiler
[x] Executing /usr/bin/c++ -fPIC -std=c++11 -fPIC -Werror -Wall -march=corei7-avx -mavx -msse4.1 -msse4.2 -fabi-version=6 -mavx2 -Winvalid-pch -c -o CMakeFiles/bluevision.dir/descriptor/histogram/integral_image.cpp.o /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/tmp/integral_i.stdout.kernavo.com.27724.BLT8ks.ii
[x] Unlink /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/c/b/960271b46a4eb133ebec4407f8b799-193981.o.tmp.stdout.kernavo.com.27724.x1URnV
[x] Unlink /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/c/b/960271b46a4eb133ebec4407f8b799-193981.o.tmp.stderr.kernavo.com.27724.rxhBqo.2
[x] Unlink /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/c/b/960271b46a4eb133ebec4407f8b799-193981.o.tmp.stderr.kernavo.com.27724.rxhBqo
[x] Copying CMakeFiles/bluevision.dir/descriptor/histogram/integral_image.cpp.o to /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/c/b/960271b46a4eb133ebec4407f8b799-193981.o via /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/c/b/960271b46a4eb133ebec4407f8b799-193981.o.kernavo.com.27724.vTjTiS (uncompressed)
[x] Stored in cache: CMakeFiles/bluevision.dir/descriptor/histogram/integral_image.cpp.o -> /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/c/b/960271b46a4eb133ebec4407f8b799-193981.o
[x] Copying /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/c/b/960271b46a4eb133ebec4407f8b799-193981.o to CMakeFiles/bluevision.dir/descriptor/histogram/integral_image.cpp.o via CMakeFiles/bluevision.dir/descriptor/histogram/integral_image.cpp.o.kernavo.com.27724.BJzcbm (uncompressed)
[x] Created from cache: /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/c/b/960271b46a4eb133ebec4407f8b799-193981.o -> CMakeFiles/bluevision.dir/descriptor/histogram/integral_image.cpp.o
[x] Added object file hash to /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/3/9/67544dd3c9bebe61712bf8bcc68c23-10829.manifest
[x] Unlink /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/tmp/integral_i.stdout.kernavo.com.27724.BLT8ks.ii
[x] Unlink /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/tmp/integral_i.stdout.kernavo.com.27724.BLT8ks
[x] Unlink /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/tmp/tmp.cpp_stderr.kernavo.com.27724.jae35Z
[x] Acquired lock /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/c/stats.lock
[x] Releasing lock /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/c/stats.lock
[x] Unlink /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/c/stats.lock
[x] Result: cache miss
[x] Unlink /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/a/3/7ac45e9e75fedfd804f2aeb01e5ed0-126212.o.tmp.stdout.kernavo.com.27876.eFOVH2
[x] Unlink /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/a/3/7ac45e9e75fedfd804f2aeb01e5ed0-126212.o.tmp.stderr.kernavo.com.27876.a4kQ4O.2
[x] Unlink /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/a/3/7ac45e9e75fedfd804f2aeb01e5ed0-126212.o.tmp.stderr.kernavo.com.27876.a4kQ4O
[x] Copying CMakeFiles/bluevision.dir/descriptor/descriptor_spatio.cpp.o to /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/a/3/7ac45e9e75fedfd804f2aeb01e5ed0-126212.o via /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/a/3/7ac45e9e75fedfd804f2aeb01e5ed0-126212.o.kernavo.com.27876.sLSNVB (uncompressed)
[x] Stored in cache: CMakeFiles/bluevision.dir/descriptor/descriptor_spatio.cpp.o -> /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/a/3/7ac45e9e75fedfd804f2aeb01e5ed0-126212.o
[x] Copying /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/a/3/7ac45e9e75fedfd804f2aeb01e5ed0-126212.o to CMakeFiles/bluevision.dir/descriptor/descriptor_spatio.cpp.o via CMakeFiles/bluevision.dir/descriptor/descriptor_spatio.cpp.o.kernavo.com.27876.CBXLMo (uncompressed)
[x] Created from cache: /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/a/3/7ac45e9e75fedfd804f2aeb01e5ed0-126212.o -> CMakeFiles/bluevision.dir/descriptor/descriptor_spatio.cpp.o
[x] Added object file hash to /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/0/c/677d29d2a852e11bc8ea97fdc27fda-9012.manifest
[x] Unlink /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/tmp/descriptor.stdout.kernavo.com.27876.4mA1kg.ii
[x] Unlink /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/tmp/descriptor.stdout.kernavo.com.27876.4mA1kg
[x] Unlink /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/tmp/tmp.cpp_stderr.kernavo.com.27876.4r9fHu
[x] Acquired lock /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/a/stats.lock
[x] Releasing lock /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/a/stats.lock
[x] Unlink /work1/gwen/cache/ccache/a/stats.lock
[x] Result: cache miss
```

Comment: Read the docs about sloppiness.